# Pulling information from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to pull specific info from individual cells to a " US$100/ft " format.
Instead I get 100.3216

Also I'm looking for a way to use shortcut keys to generate and reset the label box values instead of multiple buttons.

```vb
Private Sub GetQuote_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application

Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tcreel\Documents\quoteautofill.xlsx")

ThisDocument.Label1.Caption = "Horizontal Straight Housing & Cable                         " & _
     exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(7, "O") 'horizontal footage price'

ThisDocument.Label2.Caption = "Vertical Straight Housing & Cable                               " & _
     exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(8, "O") 'verticle footage price'

ThisDocument.Label3.Caption = "Horizontal 90-degree Elbow & Cable                          " & _
     exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(9, "O") ' hor.90° elbow price'

ThisDocument.Label4.Caption = "Vertical 90-degree Elbow & Cable                                " & _
     exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(10, "O") 'vert. 90° price'

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(7, "O")` returns it's `.value` as default, try `.text` for the displayed contents.

Comment: Looks like the text you are using Captions for should be in a cell because it's data.

Comment: instead a caption what should i use instead? and im getting run time errors when i replace " .cells " with " .text " .... again i am very green when it comes to this. the most i have done was a c++ class back in 2013 lol

Answer (score 0):

You should use code like either:

```
exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(7, "O").Text
```

(if your workbook displays the content in the desired output format), or:

```
Format(exWb.Sheets("Quote Sheet").Cells(7, "O").Value, "$#,##0.00")
```

where "$#,##0.00" specifies the desired output format.